# What is wrong with my "stars and bars" implementation?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Recently came upon a question about Bars and Stars. I can't remember it in its entirety but I got it wrong and I'm breaking my head trying to figure out exactly where I went wrong.

The question is this one https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-string-stars-bars-determine-number-stars-two-bars-within-substring-star-represented--q38765107

My code was pretty straightforward.

```rb
# First attempt
def total_stars(s, start_indices, end_indices)
  indices = start_indices.zip(end_indices)
  total_count = []
  indices.each do |start_i, end_i|
    substring = s.slice(start_i - 1, end_i)
    substring.gsub!('|', '||') # Add '||' for scan to work
    
    # Scan for '*' between '|'. Count them (-2 for the two bars). Sum them.
    count = substring.scan(/\|\*+\|/).map { |str| str.length - 2 }.reduce(&:+) || 0
    total_count.push(count)
  end

  total_count
end
```

Can anyone help me identify where I could've gone wrong? I've tried searching for the question on HackerRank and LeetCode and could not find it.

And if anyone can send me hackerrank or Leetcode link that would be great.

Comment: Your statement of the question is unclear.  In your example you said the return value is `[2, 1]`. Why `1`, as the last `'*'` is not *between* bars? Further, suppose `s  = '|**|*|**'`, `start_indices = [2]` and `end_indices = [6]`. Is the return value `[3]`, `[5]` or something else?  Please clarify and post the link to the Leetcode question. (I can't find it.)

Comment: I don't have access to LeetCode question. It was an interview screening question from HackerRank and I can't find it either. I clarified the question @CarySwoveland

Comment: @CarySwoveland in your example, the answer would be `[1]` because only **one** star is between `|`

Comment: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-string-stars-bars-determine-number-stars-two-bars-within-substring-star-represented--q38765107 looks to be the problem, and your transcription looks right. So does your code, though.

Comment: That's the exact question @Robert! How did you come to that conclusion @Cary? It is possible I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Found the answer https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/16a/s1024x612/16a7a77a-c097-4c37-a6ac-983d4f29fa16/php0gatn1.png, I'm starting to think my answer was slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see with your code is `s.slice(start_i - 1, end_i)`. That is problematic when `start_i = 0` and `end_i = s.size - 1`. For example, `"abc".slice(0-1, 2) #=> "2"`, because `-1` and `2` both index the last character of the string.

Note you can replace `reduce(&:+) || 0` with `reduce(0, &:+)`, or, better, `sum`.

I do think `substring.gsub!('|', '||')` is a bit hokey. You could instead write

```
'**|*|**|**'.scan(/(?<=\|)\*+(?=\|)/).sum(&:size) 
  #=> 3
```

where `(?<=\|)` is a *positive lookbehind*, which asserts that the match (one or more `'*'`'s) is preceded by a pipe and `(?=\|)` is a *positive lookahead*, which asserts that the match is followed by a pipe.

Here is another way.

```
def find_em(str, start_idx, end_idx)
   start_idx.zip(end_idx).map do |s,e|
     next 0 unless str[s..e].include?('|')
     str[str.index('|', s)..str.rindex('|', e)].count('*')
   end
end
```

```
find_em('**|*|**|**', [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 1, 3])
  #=> [1, 3, 3, 0, 0]
```

See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip), [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index) and [String#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rindex).

Comment: According to the problem, index starts at 1. I'm not too regex savyy so couldn't do the lookahead off the top of my head :). Your answer looks very good though.

Comment: I think I was wrong definitely on the indices. Thanks. Kinda upset I didn't catch such a silly error

Comment: looking back at this, my answer was correct. it does the same thing as yours. curiosity is killing me to figure out exactly what is wrong with my answer but owell

Comment: I'm in a bit of a rush now, so couldn't spend much time reviewing your code, but try replacing `substring = s.slice(start_i - 1, end_i)` with `substring = s.slice([start_i - 1, 0].max, end_i)`.